# Moving between galleries

Tags: jquery

Hello I have a little bit problem, because I have builded a gallery, with galleries in this one gallery, this is what I mean:

```
<div class="galleries">
<div class="gallery1"><img src="" /></div>
<div class="gallery2"><img src="" /></div>
<div class="gallery3"><img src="" /></div>
<div class="gallery4"><img src="" /></div>
<div class="gallery5"><img src="" /></div>
<div class="gallery6"><img src="" /></div>
</div>
```

I looped them, I mean that if ends 1st, then I do gallery2(); and etc.
but I would like to add arrows to move beetween them, but I don't know how can I achieve this, can somebody help me with achiving this?

Comment: you need to post your javascript code as well

Comment: Add a fiddle what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic approach is to create something for the navigation between galleries, like anchors, buttons, or anything you want:

```
<a class="prev"> < </a> 
<a class="next"> > </a>
```

Then you could use css classes to manage **active**/**hidden** galleries

```
<div id="gallery1" class="active">Gallery 1<img src="" /></div>
<div id="gallery2" class="hidden">Gallery 2<img src="" /></div>
<div id="gallery3" class="hidden">Gallery 3<img src="" /></div>
<div id="gallery4" class="hidden">Gallery 4<img src="" /></div>
<div id="gallery5" class="hidden">Gallery 5<img src="" /></div>
<div id="gallery6" class="hidden">Gallery 6<img src="" /></div>
```

Css should be:

```
.active{
    display: block;
}
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

Finally with jQuery:

```
$('.next').on('click', function(){
    if(! $('.galleries .active').is($('.galleries div').last()) ){
    $('.galleries .active')
        .removeClass("active")
        .addClass("hidden")
        .next()
        .removeClass("hidden")
        .addClass("active");
    }
});

$('.prev').on('click', function(){
    if(! $('.galleries .active').is($('.galleries div').first()) ){
        $('.galleries .active')
            .removeClass("active")
            .addClass("hidden")
            .prev()
            .removeClass("hidden")
            .addClass("active");
    }
});
```

Full demo here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3PpK6/)

---

EDIT: if you need to call different functions according to the active gallery, and **assuming that function name is equivalent to your gallery id** (just like in your example), you can add the following line in the two functions (next and prev):

```
eval($('.galleries .active').attr("id")+"()");
```

New Demo here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3PpK6/1/)

Note that this approach is totally unreccomended. Probably a better thing would be to call a wrapper function that will check ID and then call the relative function, like this:

```
loadFunctionGalleryFromID( $('.galleries .active').attr("id") );

...

function loadFunctionGalleryFromID(id){
    switch(id) {
        case "gallery1":
            gallery1();
            break;
        case "gallery2":
            gallery2();
            break;
        case "gallery3":
            gallery3();
            break;

            .......
      }
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3PpK6/3/)

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain me, how can I load a function with next gallery? I mean, if I am watching 2nd gallery, if I click on next, then jQuery should load function gallery3(), and if I will be watching 1st gallery, and I click next, then jQuery will load function gallery2();, because this is the hardest part for me

Comment: i edited my original post to answer your question. check it out